# c/fortran function memory analyser tool

Tags: c, memory

I came across some issue in which my application gives different results for relase & debug mode.
Is there any tool available by which I can check memory map difference & variable values of a function between two modes.

Comment: Is your source code available somewhere? What standard library functions does it use?

Comment: Yes.Whole code is available to me.The bug is in the Fortran fine somewhere,but its working file in debug mode,that's the reason I couldn't debug it.

Comment: What is your development tool set and which platform(s) are you developing on ?

Comment: I am workin on Sun Solaris & using Sun studio for development

Comment: Can you explain what differences you see in your results ?  Small numerical differences between debug and optimised versions of Fortran codes are not unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Unix-like operating system, you might want to have a look at [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Output differences between debug and release mode are often due to the executables having a different memory layout, thus exposing memory-related bugs that are not otherwise visible.